# Why is my TFRecord file so much bigger than csv?

Tags: tensorflow

I always thought that being a binary format, [TFRecord](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/python_io#tfrecords_format_details) will consume less space then a human-readable csv. But when I tried to compare them, I saw that it is not the case.

For example here I create a `num_rows X 10` matrix with `num_rows` labels and save it as a csv. I do the same by saving it to TFRecors:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from random import randint

num_rows = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame([[randint(0,300) for r in xrange(10)] + [randint(0, 1)] for i in xrange(num_rows)])

df.to_csv("data/test.csv", index=False, header=False)

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('data/test.bin')
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    arr = list(row)
    features, label = arr[:-1], arr[-1]
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'features' : tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=features)),
        'label':     tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[label])),
    }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Not only it takes way more time to create a binary file than a csv (2 sec VS 1 min 50 sec), but it also uses almost 2 times more space (38Mb VS 67.7Mb).

---

Do I do it correctly? How can I make the output file smaller (saw [TFRecordCompressionType](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io/TFRecordCompressionType)), but is there anything else I can do? And what is the reason for a much bigger size?

---

**Vijay's comment regarding int64** makes sense but still does not answer everything. Int64 consumes 8 bytes, because I am storing data in csv, the string representation of the integer should be of length 8. So if I do this `df = pd.DataFrame([[randint(1000000,99999999) for r in xrange(10)] for i in xrange(num_rows)])` I still get a slightly bigger size. Now it is 90.9Mb VS 89.1Mb. In additional to this csv stores 1 byte for each comma between each integers.

Comment: Is it because you are saving the features in int64 when writing to tfrecords, when they are actually in int32?.

Comment: This kind of makes sense, but then if I change it to FloatList the filesize increases to 92Mb. If by float they mean float64, then it should stay the same, otherwise it should decrease by 2 times. Also similar situation (with bigger size) is for strings.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your file is bigger is due to the overhead that TFRecords has for each row, in particular the fact that the label names are stored every time.

In your example, if you increase the number of features (from 10 to say 1000) you will observe that your tfrecord file is actually about half the size of the csv.

Also that the fact that integers are stored on 64 bits is eventually irrelevant, because the serialization uses a "varint" encoding that depends on the value of the integer, not on its initial encoding. Take your example above, and instead of a random value between 0 and 300, use a constant value of 300: you will see that your file size increases.

Note that the number of bytes used for the encoding is not exactly that of the integer itself. So a value of 255 will still need two bytes, but a value of 127 will take one byte. Interesting to know, negative values come with a huge penalty: 10 bytes for storage no matter what.

The correspondance between values and storage requirements is found in protobuf's function [`_SignedVarintSize`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/2f4489a3e504e0a4aaffee69b551c6acc9e08374/python/google/protobuf/internal/encoder.py#L96).

Comment: Is there any way to decrease or remove labels (apart from obvious changing it from 'features' to 'f' and from 'labels' to 'l'. Basically do you know a way to decrease the size of the file?

Comment: I don't. Looking at the way TFRecords are serialized, I would think this is not an option that is proposed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This may because of your generated numbers are in range 0~300, so they just need 3 bytes most to store a number, but when they are stored in tfrecords as int64, it need at least 8 bytes(not very sure) to store a number. If your generated numbers are in range 0~2^64-1, I think tfrecords file will much smaller than csv file.

Comment: This kind of makes sense, but then if I change it to FloatList the filesize increases to 92Mb. If by float they mean float64, then it should stay the same, otherwise it should decrease by 2 times. Also similar situation (with bigger size) is for strings. PS also in case of 8bytes I should generate numbers from 10000000 to 99999999. This is because csv stores data as strings so it should be just a string of 8 digits.

Comment: I did some experiments right now, I changed generated value range, both of the csv file and tfrecords file sizes are growing, csv file grows faster. So I guess that protobuf will do some compressing when serialized to string.